# How can I receive a JSON:API post of nested attributes in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, redux, json-api

Is there a “standard” approach to receiving (potentially nested) a JSON:API POST object in Rails?

The JSON:API spec uses the same format for GET / POST / PUT, etc, but rails seems to need *_attributes and accepts_nested_attributes_for. These seem incompatible.

I feel like what I'm doing must be somewhat common, yet I'm having trouble finding documentation. I'm wanting to use a React/Redux app that communicates with a Rails app using the JSON:API spec. I'm just not sure how to handle the nested associations.

Comment: There are multiple gems that can handle serializing/deserializing JSON:API. None of them can be considered "standard" as they are not part of the Rails core. https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&display=compact&q=JSON+API

Comment: None of them really work straight out the box with `accepts_nested_attributes` which is tailored specifically to the rails form helpers. You'll have to transform the hash/array of hashes into the expected `assocation_name_attribute(s)` if you want to use `accepts_nested_attributes`.

Answer (score 1):

You can [active_model_serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/) gem's Deserialization functionality.

From the [docs](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/general/deserialization.md) of the gem:

```
class PostsController < ActionController::Base
  def create
    Post.create(create_params)
  end

  def create_params
    ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse(params, only: [:title, :content, :author])
  end
end
```

The above can work with the below JSON API payload:

```
document = {
  'data' => {
    'id' => 1,
    'type' => 'post',
    'attributes' => {
      'title' => 'Title 1',
      'date' => '2015-12-20'
    },
    'relationships' => {
      'author' => {
        'data' => {
          'type' => 'user',
          'id' => '2'
        }
      },
      'second_author' => {
        'data' => nil
      },
      'comments' => {
        'data' => [{
          'type' => 'comment',
          'id' => '3'
        },{
          'type' => 'comment',
          'id' => '4'
        }]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The entire document can be parsed without specifying any options:

```
ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse(document)
#=>
# {
#   title: 'Title 1',
#   date: '2015-12-20',
#   author_id: 2,
#   second_author_id: nil
#   comment_ids: [3, 4]
# }
```

Comment: Kartikey Tanna could you show what this looks like after deserialization?

Comment: @pixelearth it's there in the docs but I updated the answer so that it is obvious

Comment: I'm mostly interested in whether this deserialization works with *_attributes and accepts_nested_attributes_for. The docs don't show this.

Comment: One thing it does say that is confusing to me is: 'Attributes/Json There is currently no deserialization for those adapters'. Maybe that means it's not possible?

Comment: @pixelearth AMS has different adapters. One we are discussing is `json_api` which supports Deserialization. Other adapters `attributes` and `json` don't.

Answer (score 0):

I saw these longs threads/issues discussions [#979](https://github.com/json-api/json-api/issues/979) and [#795](https://github.com/json-api/json-api/issues/795) on JSON:API repo days ago, that aparently seems that JSON API don't have a true solution for `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

I don't know if it is the better solution but the work around to that is disposing a route to your `belongs_to` and `has_many/has_one` associations.

Something like that:

Your **routes.rb**:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :contacts do
    resource :kind, only: [:show]
    resource :kind, only: [:show], path: 'relationships/kind'

    resource :phones, only: [:show]
    resource :phones, only: [:show], path: 'relationships/phones'

    resource :phone, only: [:update, :create, :destroy]
    # These relationships routes is merely a suggestion of a best practice
    resource :phone, only: [:update, :create, :destroy], path: 'relationships/phone'

    resource :address, only: [:show, :update, :create, :destroy]
    resource :address, only: [:show, :update, :create, :destroy], path: 'relationships/address'
  end

  root 'contacts#index'
end
```

Them implement your *controllers*.
The **phones_controller.rb** following the example above:

```
class PhonesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_contacts

  def update
    phone = Phone.find(phone_params[:id])

    if phone.update(phone_params)
      render json: @contact.phones, status: :created, location: contact_phones_url(@contact.id)
    else
      render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /contacts/1/phone
  def destroy
    phone = Phone.find(phone_params[:id])
    phone.destroy
  end

  # POST contacts/1/phone
  def create
    @contact.phones << Phone.new(phone_params)

    if @contact.save
      render json: @contact.phones, status: :created, location: contact_phones_url(@contact.id)
    else
      render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # GET /contacts/1/phones
  def show
    render json: @contact.phones
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_contacts
      @contact = Contact.find(params[:contact_id])
    end

    def phone_params
      ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse(params)
    end
end
```

By doing that you should be able to request a Phone *POST* normally through a contact separately, like so:

POST on ***http://localhost:3000/contacts/1/phone*** with the body:

```
{
    "data": {
            "type": "phones",
            "attributes": {
                "number": "(+55) 91111.2222"
            }
    }
}
```

The response or GET on ***http://localhost:3000/contacts/1/phones***:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "40",
            "type": "phones",
            "attributes": {
                "number": "(55) 91111.2222"
            },
            "relationships": {
                "contact": {
                    "data": {
                        "id": "1",
                        "type": "contacts"
                    },
                    "links": {
                        "related": "http://localhost:3000/contacts/1"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Hope that answer